# Contar número de NULL en una tabla

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla con 800 columnas, y me gustaría contar el número total de NULL almacenados en la misma. El trabajo es obvio para una columna en particular, y se podría hacer por ejemplo con:

```
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table WHERE column IS NULL)
```

Pero esto para 800 columnas se hace bastante inmanejable.

¿Se podría hacer esto para cada columna recorriéndolas todas mediante una función?

Comment: Suena a que la tabla necesita un ajuste a su diseño...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La única forma que tienes es construir una sentencia dinámica usando alguna vista de columnas y tablas del motor para poder armar cada uno de los `SUM`. Esto tiene sus límites, en particular con el tamaño de un [`NVARCHAR(MAX)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) (2 gb), pero si no llegas a ese límite puede servirte.

```
DECLARE @Tabla  VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SQL    nVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Tabla  = 'Nombre de la tabla'

SELECT  @SQL = 'SELECT ' + CHAR(10)

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + '       SUM(CASE WHEN ' + sc.name + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + ' + CHAR(10)
    FROM syscolumns sc
    INNER JOIN sysobjects so
    ON sc.id = so.id
    WHERE so.name = @Tabla

SELECT  @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 3 ) + CHAR(10) + '    FROM ' + @Tabla

EXECUTE  sp_executesql @SQL
```

Explicación:

- Definimos una variable `@SQL` para construir la consulta y una `@Tabla` para indicar el nombre de la tabla
- Completamos la consulta accediendo a las vistas [`sysobjects`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) y [`syscolumns`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscolumns-transact-sql), hay vistas más actuales, pero estas son bien compatibles con versiones de SQLServer actuales y antiguas.
- Por último ejecutamos las sentencia mediante [`sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que quieres es contar el número de valores `NULL`, es decir, que si un registro tiene 3 columnas con valor `NULL` cuente como 3, podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN columna1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN columna2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN columna3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tabla
```

Si lo que quieres es contar los registros que tienen todas las columnas a `NULL` sería algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla
WHERE COALESCE(columna1, columna2, columna3) IS NULL
```

Comment: Me parece que lo que quiere es evitar que tener que poner `columna1, columna 2, ..., columna799, columna800`